# Schräg, seltsam, komisch und merkwürdig

Tags: adjective, synonym

Sind diese Adjektive irgendwie Synonyme?
Gibt es Sätze wo man nur ein bestimmtes Adjektiv verwendet kann oder sind austauschbar?
Danke im voraus.

Comment: In dieser allgemeinen Form sehe ich nicht, was ein Wörterbuch nicht beantworten kann, siehe z. B. [DWDS: merkwürdig](https://www.dwds.de/wb/merkwürdig).

Comment: @guidot: Dann solltest Du vielleicht dafür stimmen, die Frage zu schließen. Das Interface sieht genau diesen Fall als Grund vor.

Comment: @userunknown: das ist mir bekannt; wenn ein Moderator dafür "stimmt", ist die Frage allerdings sofort zu. Interessant, dass bisher nur eine(r) für das Schließen gestimmt hat, aber drei Antworten vorliegen... Siehe auch diese [Meta-Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/840/are-we-closing-too-many-questions).

Comment: Dann ist die Frage sofort zu - na und? Wird man nicht Moderator, um Verantwortung zu übernehmen? Ist das nicht ein klarer Fall, hier? Können die User nicht für "Reopen" voten, wenn Ihnen Deine Entscheidung zuwider sein sollte?

Answer (score 2):

*Seltsam* und *merkwürdig* sind weitgehend synonym und austauschbar.

*Schräg* hat als ursprüngliche Wortbedeutung "nicht parallel oder rechtwinklig, in einem Winkel verlaufend". Umgangssprachlich wird es in übertragener Bedeutung verwendet für "inkongruent, unpassend, eigenwillig". Auch in der übertragenen Bedeutung ist es nicht ganz synonym zu *seltsam* und *merkwürdig*, da es eine andere Wertung ausdrückt.

*Komisch* hat als ursprüngliche Wortbedeutung "zum Lachen reizend", kann aber im übertragenen Sinn auch als Synonym für *seltsam* und *merkwürdig* verwendet werden, ähnlich wie das englische "funny".

Answer (score 0):

Sie sind keine Synonyme. Jedes hat eine etwas andere Bedeutung.

Schräg: Eine Sache, die so unerwartet anders ist, dass man nicht weiß, was man davon halten soll. Man tendiert eher aber nicht zwingend auf Distanz zu gehen.

Seltsam: Eine Sache, die nicht der Erwartung entspricht, ist seltsam.

Komisch: Komisch kann lustig bedeuten aber auch seltsam. Es ist somit bedingt austauschbar.

Merkwürdig: Weitestgehend austauschbar mit seltsam. Enthält meiner Meinung nach noch eine kleine Konnotation von Innehalten und ist ein Ticken stärker als seltsam.

Comment: Wenn Du zu "schräg" sagst, dass man nicht zwingend auf Distanz geht mit der Formulierung - willst Du damit sagen, dass alle anderen Begriffe zwingend auf Distanz gehen? Die Sätze beschreiben keine disjunkten Sachverhalte und helfen daher nicht weiter. Bei Merkwürdig relativierst Du noch doppelt, mit "meiner Meinung nach" und "kleine" Konnotation. Du würdest zustimmen, dass nicht alle "merkwürdig" als "ein Ticken stärker" betrachten?

Comment: @user unknown Es gibt Situationen, wo sie austauschbar sind und es gibt Situationen, wo sie es nicht sind. Natürlich muss ich da relativieren. Die Konnotation bei merkwürdig lässt sich nicht über sinnverwandte Wortfelder ausdrücken. Ich wüsste zumindest nicht, wie. Es ist also grundsätzlich diskutierbar. Hätte ich den Part mit der Meinung weggelassen, wäre ich dafür kritisiert worden, dass das persönliches Empfinden, zumindest nicht objektiv definiert ist. Ich nehme es hinzu und werde kritisiert. Leuten wie ihnen kann man es nicht Recht machen, glaube ich.

Comment: Du solltest nicht hier sein, um es irgendwem Recht zu machen, noch um auf Zuruf Bedeutungsunterschiede zu finden, auch wenn das hier Breitensport ist. Wenn man keine Unterschiede benennen kann, dann kann es vielleicht ein anderer oder versucht sich mit Belegen für die Behauptung, dass es keine gibt. Und schweigen ist auch immer eine Option.

Answer (score -1):

So eine Frage lässt sich nicht mit wenigen Beispielen beantworten. Vorschlag: Recherchiere selbst bei den DWDS Wortprofilen der angefragten Wörter, dort kann man jeweils zwei Wörter auf ihre möglichen Kontexte hin vergleichen. Hier ist z.B. der [Link](https://www.dwds.de/wp/?q=seltsam&comp-method=diff&comp=merkw%C3%BCrdig&pos=Adjektiv&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=100&view=table) für *seltsam* und *merkwürdig*.

Comment: While true to some degree, this does not really answer the question. What does this add, especially given the existing two answers?

Comment: Ja und nein. Wenn ich auf diese Tabellen schaue, fällt mir vieles ein. Überraschend sind für mich die doch recht eindeutigen Gebrauchsunterschiede. Gefragt ist hier aber nach einer Art Quintessenz aus all dem, und da behaupte ich: Die lässt sich nicht einfach ziehen. Z.B. könnte ich auf den Gedanken verfallen, 'seltsam' sei etwas, das zwar irritiert, dem man aber noch eine tief verborgene, geheimnisvolle Erklärbarkeit zutraut, 'merkwürdig' hingegen etwas, an dessen innerer Logik man zweifelt. So etwas sind Impressionen, dazu fehlt es an Belegen. Hier können solche Tabellen helfen, zumal ...

Comment: ... [zumal:] Wenn man die Wörter als einzelnes Lemma, ohne Vergleichslemma aufruft, kann man sich durch Klick auf ein Wort in einer der Tabellen Beispiele anzeigen lassen. Zumindest hat man da mal authentische Beispiele im Kontext und nicht spekulativ, oft fehlerhaft erfundene, bei denen Kleinigkeiten nicht exakt passen. Z.B. wunderte mich die große Zahl an Kombinationen von 'seltsam + Weg'. Viele Beispiele dazu beruhen auf der Wendung 'seltsame Wege gehen', durchaus mit Anspielungen auf 'Schicksalhaftigkeit'. Googelt man dann 'seltsame' vs. 'merkwürdige Wege' gibt es für beides viele Treffer.

Comment: ... Damit ist eine Spekulation hinfällig. Dennoch unterscheiden sich die Treffer-Kontexte. Mit anderen Worten: Mit ein paar launigen, impressionistischen Vermutungen über Bedeutungs- bzw. Gebrauchsunterschiede ist es nicht getan, obwohl man sie sich schnell ausgedacht hätte. Und: Ein wenig eigene Recherche könnte da nicht schaden. Die Frage ist für einfache Antworten zu 'mächtig' - was dem Fragesteller vielleicht nicht klar war.